# divide the transition states of Markov chain

Tags: beamer, math-mode

[image]I'd like to divide the transition states of Markov chain by  dashed sloped lines between them. This lines should not connect the transition states

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: At the moment it is unclear what you want to achieve. Can you show what you have so far and describe in more detail what you want to have instead? Otherwise it is hardly possible to help.

Comment: Can you show us how you draw the Markov chain? We can then probably add the division lines, but we need to see which packages etc. you use to draw the chain, because as there is more then one way to draw such a chain, there is more then one way to add those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

In future you should always to your question add what you try so far and where you stuck in your effort to solve in problem. It is not fun to wrote code from scratch ... you should help us to help you ...

Anyway, since you are beginner on site, I do exception and wrote (for exercise) the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,
                chains
                }
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, semithick,
      node distance = 22mm,
        start chain = going right,
state/.append style = {thick, fill=gray!10,
                       inner sep=5pt, minimum width=2em,
                       font=\sffamily\Large,
                       on chain},
                       ]
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
  \node (s\i)[state]    {\i};
\draw[->]   (s0) edge[bend left] node (a1) {$1$}   (s1)
            (s1) edge[bend left] node (a2) {$1/3$} (s2)
            (s2) edge[bend left] node (a3) {$3/4$} (s3)
%
            (s3) edge[bend left] node (b3) {$1$}   (s2)
            (s2) edge[bend left] node (b2) {$1/4$} (s1)
            (s1) edge[bend left] node (b1) {$2/3$} (s0);
% sloped lines crossing edges 
\draw (b1.west) -- (a1.east);
\draw (b2.west) -- (a2.east);
\draw (b3.west) -- (a3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
since all edges are bend to left, above MWE can be rewritten in slightly more concise form which gives the same result as above:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, semithick,
      node distance = 22mm,
        start chain = going right,
state/.append style = {thick, fill=gray!10,
                       inner sep=5pt, minimum width=2em,
                       font=\sffamily\Large,
                       on chain},
  every edge/.style = {draw, -{Stealth[bend]}, bend left}
  ]
\foreach \i in {0,...,3}
  \node (s\i)[state]    {\i};
\path   (s0) edge node (a1) {$1$}   (s1)
        (s1) edge node (a2) {$1/3$} (s2)
        (s2) edge node (a3) {$3/4$} (s3)
%
        (s3) edge node (b3) {$1$}   (s2)
        (s2) edge node (b2) {$1/4$} (s1)
        (s1) edge node (b1) {$2/3$} (s0);
% sloped lines crossing edges
\draw   (b1.west) -- (a1.east);
\draw   (b2.west) -- (a2.east);
\draw   (b3.west) -- (a3.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Use of both above MWE in `beamer` should not be a problem. If it will appear for any reasons, please ask new question (which will contain MWE)